# How to use a Color attribute with a Geometry Proximity node to change vertex color based on depth

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-colors

The set up here is pretty straight forward. Take a shape, get its volume, generate leaves within that volume and set the vertex color based on how near the surface the leaf is.

My solution was to use geometry proximity node to measure the instance's distance from the original volume's surface. When I plug the output of the geometry proximity into a map range node and then into a Scale instances node, I can see its working correctly with surface leaves being smaller. However, when I plug that same output into a color ramp I do not get the expected output. Instead each leaf seems to have the same vertex color regardless of where they are in the volume.

I feel I am missing something here and any advice would really help me out. If I can solve this problem then I can start generating all sorts of low-poly optimised bushes. Thanks!
[image: My node setup]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to color vertices you should color it under material nodes ...

Use your set "color" atribute in *Attribute* node of material nodes and than ColorRamp to *Material Output* or what ever ... don't forget to use *Realize Instances* node.

[image]
[image]

[image]